# Error terms and Residual in Time Series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, mathematical-statistics, forecasting

I started learning Time Series Forecasting and the below questions keep my head confused a lot.

Many papers mention that the forecast errors have to be normally distributed and what about the white noise error term, guess white noise wouldn't be fitting into the normal distribution of errors. Most importantly the idea for any time series forecast model is to have the error term that should be completely white noise? so that we covered all factors/relationship in predicting a variable and the only error left is white noise?

Forecast function= signal + white noise

Signal contains residuals (reducible errors) and white noise are irreducible errors?

So the normality of errors is only for the residual errors(reducible errors) and does not include White noise?

So for every Time Series forecast we calculate the Residual errors( like RSME) separately and check for White noise separately?

Comment: Hi: I don't know what you're reading but your statements don't sound correct. If you need a book recommendation, send a request but provide your background so the correct book can be recommended.  The basic idea ( but you need a book. I can't explain this here ) is that the residuals from the model are estimates of the error terms and the error term is assumed to be a discrete version of white noise. Theoretically speaking, white noise doesn't exist because it's the derivative of brownian motion. But, in practice, people use the normal error term to obtain a discrete version of white noise.

Comment: Hi: I forgot to mention that brownian motion doesn't have a derivative which is why, technically speaking, white noise doesn't exist. But practitioners model it by using the normally distributed error term. One can get away with this in discrete time because white noise is continuous so one needs to discretize even if the derivative did exist.

Comment: Can you please explain why we want the errors to be normally distributed?... If we make the errors fit into the normal distribution doesn't it affect the randomness of errors?

Comment: Also the White noise is something that will remain after the residual errors are modelled which cannot be predicted as it shows no correlation. Please mention any good Time Series Forecasting book.. Currently I'm reading Hyndman's Forecasting Principles..

Comment: Hi: you assume that they are normally distributed because that's about the best way you can model them as a white noise process in discrete time. I have one of Rob's books ( not sure if he's written more than one ) but I've never read it so I don't know the level.  I think something by Chris Chatfield might be more appropriate for you. What is your academic background ?  let us know if  undergrad or grad and the field you are in.